# Hosting RabbitMQ Consumers in .NET Enviornment

Tags: windows-services, rabbitmq

My question is whats the best way to host RabbitMQ consumers? The goal is to have these running as independent units that can be scaled out independently according to their usage.Windows service? (consumer per service?), WCF binding(seems deprecated)? ServiceStack bidning ?

Ideally what I would want is a biding to the Queue in RabbitMQ itself so as soon a message comes in a consumer thread is spawned and consumes the message (similar to msq bidning in WCF) Below are some I'm aware. Please advise

-

Answer (score 0):

I wont speak to the "Best way" since it's subjective and primarily influenced by experience and preference. You're going to get the greatest flexibility and access to features from using the [RabbitMQ.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client) directly rather than a framework, but a framework can offer productivity if your requirements fits within its use-case.

### ServiceStack.RabbitMQ

A benefit of using [ServiceStack's Rabbit MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ) support is that you're able to re-use existing ServiceStack Services and consume them via Rabbit MQ, which apart from the re-usability benefits, allows you to develop and test your Services via HTTP which offers better introspection by being able to invoke Services from a url as well as access to tools like Web Inspector and Fiddler.

[ServiceStack's Rabbit MQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client) includes both high-level client and server libraries which abstracts the low-level details to offer a typed API that lets you [publish POCO messages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#publishing-messages):

```
using (var mqClient = new RabbitMqMessageFactory("localhost"))
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "World" });
}
```

As well as a Typed API to [Configure ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#adding-rabbit-mq-support-to-servicestack) to handle the `Hello` Request DTO:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer());

    var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();

    mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(ExecuteMessage);
    mqServer.Start();
}
```

ServiceStack [high-level MQ Server API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging) can also be easily configured to use a different MQ Server should you ever wish to switch to use another MQ Server instead of RabbitMQ in future. Currently it supports Redis MQ and in-memory providers with support for [SQS in development](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/Sqs).

#### Scalability

MQ Servers are "naturally scalable", in that you can naturally load-balance servers by just starting more of them (configured to look at the same MQ Broker) without needing to change existing client behavior.

#### [Allocating multiple threads for specific operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#allocating-multiple-threads-for-specific-operations)

By default ServiceStack uses one long-running background thread to handle normal and priority MQ's for each different message type. You can increase the throughput for specific messages by specifying the number of background threads to use at registration, e.g:

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<Hello>(ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads:4);
```

This will start 4 long-running background threads to handle `Hello` messages.

#### Limitations

ServiceStack's high-level [ServiceStack.RabbitMq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.RabbitMq) package is [opinionated in how it configures and handles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#message-workflow) the In, Out, Response and DLQ's for each Message Type. The MQ Service is focused on providing another endpoint for consuming your ServiceStack Services via a Rabbit MQ broker, utilizing the [Request/Reply messaging pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/RequestReply.html). This means it doesn't provide access other RabbitMQ features which would require using the Rabbit MQ Client library directly. Other than the Request/Reply pattern we're currently [evaluating how best to add support for broadcast messages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/992) as well.